# Getting the calculated font-size of a div

Tags: javascript, dom, font-size

As we know, the font-size of a HTML-element is either set explicitly like `style="font-size:10px"` or calculated by the browser according to rules and properties from style sheets and parent properties.

It could be a rather complex task to calculate the font-size value in javascript as the correct result might depend on classes that do not necessarily exist in the elements className attribute.

Is there a way I can get the calculated font-size directly, like `div.style['calculated-font-size']` ? - thanx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

function elementCurrentStyle(element, styleName){
        if (element.currentStyle){
            var i = 0, temp = "", changeCase = false;
            for (i = 0; i < styleName.length; i++)
                if (styleName[i] != '-'){
                    temp += (changeCase ? styleName[i].toUpperCase() : styleName[i]);
                    changeCase = false;
                } else {
                    changeCase = true;
                }
            styleName = temp;
            return element.currentStyle[styleName];
        } else {
            return getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(styleName);
        }
    }

```
alert(elementCurrentStyle(myDiv,"font-size"));
```

I've describe this "[getting computed style](http://salaciak.blogspot.com/2011/02/javascript-dom-how-to-get-elements.html)" issue few weeks ago here.

cheers,

Comment: Thank you for the code: My question, why not directly use ```getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(styleName);```?